# Could not find method Compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.3] on DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.android.support', name='appcompat-v7', version='25.0.3', configuration='default'}.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager

I have no idea on how this could be occuring, i've checked over the files multiple timesbut yet, i cant find what is going wrong, if you have the slightest idea of what is going wrong, please let me know.

Comment: post your build.gradle files (top level and app files)

Comment: Basegameutils - https://pastebin.com/41b6xXqi

Comment: Ballin.gradle (main) - https://pastebin.com/1vrgCKfR

Comment: android.gradle - https://pastebin.com/F9k0fGa8

Comment: You can't specify the dependencies in the top level files, at least for the android project

Comment: Got it to work, however new issue ; Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [Ballin:BaseGameUtils:1.0] C:\Users\snell_000\Desktop\Ballin\BaseGameUtils\build\intermediates\bundles\default\AndroidManifest.xml
 Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.example.games.basegameutils" to force usage

Comment: You can find the answer to the 2nd issue below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue

> Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.3] 
>   on DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='com.android.support', name='appcompat-v7', version='25.0.3', configuration='default'}.

happens because your are specifying the `dependencies` block in the top-level file at least for the android project.

The second issue

> Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [Ballin:BaseGameUtils:1.0]

happens because in your **android** module you are using

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
```

}

but you are adding a dependency (BaseGameUtils) which has minSdk=15.
You have to change the `minSdkVersion` in your android project to 15.